# I can't use MySQLi in my ubuntu server. mysqli_fetch_all() is not defined?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, mysqli

A few days ago I made the migration from Windows to Ubuntu as my server. I've been doing pretty well but I've had problems with Apache since day one.

I've finally gotten somewhere, but now I'm stuck at this problem with using a MySQLi method in my PHP log (in `/var/log/apache2`):

`[Tue Jul 14 19:23:15.326084 2015] [:error] [pid 16858] [client 71.76.17.180:59078] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all() in /var/www/hausofalexander.ml/index.php on line 6`

In `phpinfo()` MySQLi is showing as enabled. You can see the info at http://www.hausofalexander.ml/info.php.

I am completely lost. If you need some more info just ask. Thanks!

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_all()` is only available if the MySQL Native Driver is installed, which for Linux it usually is not. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). Installing it requires recompiling the binary with support enabled.

Comment: @HoboSapiens YES! Thank you. I didn't realise I didn't have that! Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hobo Sapiens points out in the comment the function/method [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) is only available [if](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php) the [mysqlnd library](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) is used.

I'm not an Ubuntu guy, but you might try

```
sudo php5enmod mysqlnd
```

and if this seems to work (no obvious error message) restart the httpd and then check the output of phpinfo() for a mysqlnd section.

Comment: That really worked out-of-the-box? wow. I was just going to edit the answer and mention that there seems to be a php5-mysqlnd package which might have to be installed manually before using php5enmod, http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php/php5-mysqlnd - but apparently it's not necessary.

Answer (score -2):

**Available only with mysqlnd**
if you use PHP version under 5.4.0 , you should install the mysqlnd
 http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php
sorry for brevious answer it was totally wrong

Comment: Not sure where you got this idea. See [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Comment: yes you are right , and your answer is in the same page you post :**MySQL Native Driver Only **

**Available only with mysqlnd.**

As mysqli_fetch_all() returns all the rows as an array in a single step, it may consume more memory than some similar functions such as mysqli_fetch_array(), which only returns one row at a time from the result set. Further, if you need to iterate over the result set, you will need a looping construct that will further impact performance.